# How to make Python go through URLs in a text file, check their status codes, and exclude all ones with 404 error?

Tags: python, http, python-requests, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

I tried the following script, but unfortunately the output file is identical to the input file. I'm not sure what's wrong with it.

```
import requests

url_lines = open('banana1.txt').read().splitlines()

remove_from_urls = []

for url in url_lines:
    remove_url = requests.get(url)
    print(remove_url.status_code)
    if remove_url.status_code == 404:
        remove_from_urls.append(url)
        continue
        
url_lines = [url for url in url_lines if url not in remove_from_urls]
print(url_lines)

# Save urls example
with open('banana2.txt', 'w+') as file:
    for item in url_lines:
        file.write(item + '\n')
```

Comment: Are you sure that at least one URL in your input file will lead to a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no error in your code, but there are few things that would help to make it more readable and consistent. The first course of action should be to make sure there is at least one url that would return a 404 status code.

Edit: After providing the actual URL.

### The 404 problem

In your case, the problem is the Twitter actually does **not** return 404 error for your "Not found" url. You can test it using `curl`:

```
$ curl -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" "https://twitter.com/davemeltzerWON/status/1321279214365016064"
200
```

Or using Python:

```py
import requests
response = requests.get("https://twitter.com/davemeltzerWON/status/1321279214365016064")
print(response.status_code)
```

The output for both should be `200`.

Since Twitter is a JavaScript application that loads its content after it has been processed in browser, you cannot find the information you are looking for in the HTML response. You would need to use something like Selenium to actually process the JavaScript for you and then you would be able to look for actual text like "not found" on the web page.

### Code review

Please make sure to close the file properly. Also, `file` object is a lines iterator, you can convert it to list very easily. Another trick to make the code more readable is to make use of Python `set`. So you may read the file like this:

```py
with open("banana1.txt") as fid:
    url_lines = set(fid)
```

Then you simply remove all the links that do not work:

```py
not_working = set()
for url in url_lines:
    if requests.get(url).status_code == 404:
        not_working.add(url)

working = url_lines - not_working

with open("banana2.txt", "w") as fid:
    fid.write("\n".join(working))
```

Also, if some of the links point to the same server, you should make use of `requests.Session` class:

```py
from requests import Session
session = Session()
```

Then replace `requests.get` with `session.get`, you should get some performance boost since the Session uses keep-alive connection and many other things.

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much for your help!! So I've been testing the script, and it looks good when it comes to providing status codes. The only problem is that for some reason, 404 URLs are not being excluded. In fact, the output file has many 404 URLs. Do you happen to know why this occurs? Thanks! (Here's an example of a 404 link: https://twitter.com/davemeltzerWON/status/1321279214365016064)

Comment: @facialrecognition I edited the answer to include debugging of your URL